# Not received email using dialog "Save your Copy" in "In Person" signing

Tags: c#-4.0, docusignapi

Not received email that was typed in textbox "Email Address" using dialog "Save your Copy" in "In Person" signing.
While signing the envelope in In-Person mode there is an window (popup) to send a copy of the document in an email. We have entered the email (many times and different email services) but no email received. Checked settings in the DocuSign portal account but not able to find any setting for this. Please let us know how to enable the save a copy email in DocuSign.

We using DocuSign SOAP API under C#.
For InPererson Recipient we add :

```
new Recipient
{
    Email = "email of host recipient",
    UserName = "name of host recipient",
    SignerName = "name of current recipient",
    ID = "id current recipient",
    Type = RecipientTypeCode.InPersonSigner,
    RoutingOrder = 2,
    RequireIDLookup = false,
    CaptiveInfo =
    new RecipientCaptiveInfo {ClientUserId = "special id of current recipient"}
};
```

And we open docusign token url (RequestRecipientToken method) in new browser window without iframe we open it in IE 8-11 and Google Chrome

What we have to specify in addition to this , when creating and sending envelope or in account preferences of main account in docusign.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, keep in mind that the email you're describing will only be sent upon Completion of the Envelope -- so if there are other recipients after the In-Person signer in the routing order for the Envelope, the In-Person signer wouldn't receive the email until all recipients have completed their required actions and the Envelope is complete.

Second, you might want to verify (in **Preferences >> Features** within the DocuSign web console) that these two settings are set as shown here:

[image: DS settings]

These settings control whether or not emails are sent to "embedded/captive" recipients. Even though you're using "In-Person" signing -- it sounds like you're launching the host's signing session using "Embedded Signing" (i.e., RequestRecipientToken), so these settings might be affecting whether or not the email actually gets sent to the signer.

Comment: Uncheck "Suppress Emails to Embedded Signers" was helpful. 
Thanks Kim